# Удаление объекта из массива. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Есть следующая коллекция

```
{
    "_id": 0,
    "title": "A blog post",
    "comments": [
        {},
        {
            "name": "joe",
            "email": "joe@gmail.com",
            "content": "how you doin?)))"
        }
    ]
}
```

Нужно удалить первый пустой объект в массиве "comments"

Answer (score 1):

Удалить все пустые объекты в массиве в первом найденном документе:

```
db.items.update(
{
    "comments":{}
},
{
    "$pull": { 
        "comments": { $in:[{}] }
    }
})
```

Удалить первый пустой объект в массиве в первом найденном документе:

```
db.items.update(
{
    "comments.0":{}
}, 
{
    "$pop": { "comments": -1 }
})
```

Чтобы удалить во всех документах, нужно добавить третий параметр:

```
{ "multi": true }
```